# 404 Error while serving files with django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-settings

I want to access logs easily on my app so I created a page for that, I click on a button and it download the log.
But I get a 404 error when I try to do that, I've set static files and media files

here are my settings

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "frontend/static",
]
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
LOG_URL = 'static/logs/'
LOG_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static/logs')
```

and here are my urls

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.LOG_URL, document_root = settings.LOG_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It works when I access /media/path/to/media.file, but not for /static/logs/path/to/logs.txt, it's the same configuration for both urls so I know I miss a point, but how could I fix it? Is it because I used static and not media? Thx a lot

Comment: Generally log files doesn't fall under static files.

Comment: Ok it's just that static files can't be served? Or is it just not the best practice ? Thank you for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you deployed your Django application?
Better add media/log folder path while serving application on the web.

Comment: Ok so I should put the logs in the same media folder that actually works? What's the difference? I guess it'll works but I'd like to know why the same urls conf works for media and not for statics.
Thank you for your answer I'll try that asap

Comment: Where you have deployed your application?

Comment: My app is local, not already deployed, I've just set a virtualenv for the dependencies, I'll have to make my server serves the files when I'll deploy it, but if I understand how it works, it'll be easier.
I'll try your solution with the media folder, and if it works, I'll just set permissions to this specific log folder

Comment: Cool. This will also help to manage media files on one place.

Comment: Thank you, it works just fine, I guess I wanted to separate files in differents folders but it's not the best thing to do. Thank you for the tip :)

Comment: You are create multiple folder inside media folder.

Comment: Yes, I have now a csv folder where I put some data and the logs, it just looked a bit weird to have logs at the same place. But it's way easier like that